# Megillah 9a: Translating the Torah to Greek

Tags: translation, septuagint

The Gemara in Megillah 9a tells the story of Ptolemy forcing the sages to translate the Torah. Does anyone know of other accounts of this story. I'm especially curious why Ptolemy had the Sages separated to translate independently. In the version of the story recorded by Aristeas, he says that the Jews translated the Torah voluntarily. The Yaavetz to Megillah says that is a different story than the one in Megillah, although he seems to contradict himself in his commentary to Maseches Sofrim.

In addition, Maseches Sofrim seems to imply that the tragedy of translating the Torah was not the translation of the seventy sages but an initial attempt by five other sages. This seems to contradict other sources that the tragedy was the translation of 70.

Can anyone shed any light on these issues, or just refer to other sources beyond the ones I quoted?

Comment: Josephus talks about this.

Comment: [R. Azariah De Rossi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azariah_dei_Rossi) translated into Hebrew the entire account of Aristeas in the second section of Meor Einayim.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE: Thanks, but he just summarizes Aristeas.

Comment: @Alex: The Yaavetz refers to Rossi in his comments on Megillah. Interestingly, in his responsa, he writes that Rossi is not reliable and should not be consulted at all. I'm not sure how to reconcile that with his comments in Megillah, or which one came first or second.

Comment: In reference to the Yaavetz - I haven't examined the sources yet, but in general, lots of early-to-mid achronim attacked and rebuked Rabbi de Rossi for his explanations of Jewish history and Chazalic midrashim/aggadatot.

Comment: @N.T. In Imre Binah ch.7 [and end of ch.8] he attempts to reconcile (and correct) the dissimilar stories; see [this](https://www.academia.edu/37546885/Joanna_Weinberg_Azariah_de_Rossi_and_Septuagint_Traditions_Italia_vol_5_no_1_2_1985_7_35) too. FWIW, Emden’s notes to ME were published in Emet LeYaacov (2017, subtitled Miyide Abir Yaacov) and I did not see any glosses on the relevant sections.

Comment: @oliver Which Imre Binah? There are about a dozen on Hebrewbooks.

Comment: @N.T. *Ein hachi nami*

Comment: @N.T. Apologies, given your earlier comments I assumed you were more familiar with de Rossi’s book under discussion. IB is a section in his Meor Einayim (=ME). [This](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20254&st=&pgnum=140&hilite=) is the piece I referenced.